# Taking input from ports

Tags: assembly, 8051

I am learning 8051 assembly programming. I read in my book "In order make a port as input port, the port must be programmed by writing 1 to all its bits." Isn't this wrong, though?

If I set all the bits to one, and want to input `1010` at input, I will press button attached to 2nd pin and 4th pin to input 1010, but port will read all 1's. I have tried it on Keil uVision Simulation and found this problem.

Is this a problem or I am misunderstanding it?

```
org 00h

Reset:

mov P0,#00h
mov P1,#00h
mov P2,#00h
mov P3,#00h

TakeInput:

jb P2.0,Addition// in assembler simulation, this condition is true if I set P2 to #0ffh, which is not required. The user should set this bit for making this condition true

sjmp TakeInput


Addition:
```

mov A,P0
    add A,P1

```
mov P3,A

acall Delay

ajmp Reset


Delay:

mov R0,#1

here:

mov R1,#1

again:

djnz R1,again

djnz R0,here

ret

end
```

If I don't reset all the ports to 0, so the jump instructions which depend on a port value by default become true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the correct way, there must be something wrong with your simulation.
The 8051 pins have this kind of circuit:

[image: pin circuit]

([source](http://www.mikroe.com/img/publication/8051-books/programming-8051-mcu/chapter/ch2/03.gif))

Note the pullup to `Vcc` is optional, check the datasheet of your particular chip.

This circuit works such that if you set a pin to `0`, the output will be pulled to ground and can only be read as `0` because externally you can't pull it high. If you want to allow both levels to be input, you have to set the pin to `1`. In this case you can:

1. leave output floating if you have internal pullups (reads as `1`)
2. pull output to `Vcc` (reads as `1`)
3. pull output to ground (reads as `0`)

It follows that if you connect a button you should wire it such that it pulls the pin to ground. Add an external pullup resistor if required.

**Update**
to make this point clear: if you wire the button as directed above (ie. pushed button grounds the pin) the input will be read as `1` if button **is not** pressed, and as `0` if button **is** pressed. This is the usual way to connect buttons.

Illustration using `MCU 8051 IDE`. Notice two switches are connected to port 1 pins 7 and 6 (ie. the two top bits), one is open the other is closed (pushed).

---

If the port bits are set to zero, input will be zero no matter the state of the switches:
[image: port bits set to 0]

---

If the port bits are set to one, input will be `1` for an open and `0` for a closed switch:
[image: port bits set to 1]

The red wiring leading to the leftmost switch indicates that `P1.7` is at `Vcc` (because output is `1` and it is not pulled down by the switch).

Comment: This is the code, If I want to input `1010` I would have to turn off rest of the bits so for ease, I initialize the ports with zero.

Comment: If you set all pins to `0`, you should never see a `1` input with standard 8051 ports because then the pin is pulled to ground (see the circuit diagram).

Comment: So you mean simulation works in a different way than the 8051 port itself. Will my code run fine on 8051

Comment: Updated the answer. Simulation works correctly here (matching the real device).